# Slider with Appearance "Labeled" Gives Too Much Space

Tags: bugs, gui-construction, output

Without `Appearance -> "Labeled"` `Sliders` take up the expected space.

```
Framed[Slider[.5, ImageSize -> #]] & /@ {Tiny, Small, Medium, Large} // Column
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However, when you add `Appearance -> "Labeled"` far too much space is allocated.

```
Framed[Slider[.5, ImageSize -> #, 
     Appearance -> "Labeled"]] & /@ {Tiny, Small, Medium, Large} // Column
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For now I am rolling my own with

```
Framed@Row[{Slider[Dynamic[x], {0, 1, 0.01}, ImageSize -> Tiny], Dynamic[x]}, Spacer[1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Is this a bug or am I missing something?
Version 11.1.0 on Win 7 Ent

---

CASE:3887274

Comment: I see the same on 11.0.0.0 OSX.

Comment: Reported to WRI. CASE:3887274

Comment: An old bug, I see it even in Mathematica 8.0.4 on Win7x64.

Answer (score 4):

another quick fix

```
Framed[Slider[.666, ImageSize -> First@#, Appearance -> "Labeled"], 
FrameMargins -> {{1, -Last@#}, {2, 2}}] & /@ {{Tiny, 30}, {Small, 
60}, {Medium, 160}, {Large, 360}} // Column
```

[image]